# Retrieve the type of an unnamed struct for using it in a member function

Tags: c++, c++14

How to get the type of an unnamed struct for using it in a member function?

```
struct {
  using P = int;  // What should be instead of int?

  bool operator<(const P& r) {
    return false;
  }
} obj1, obj2;

int main() {
  obj1 < obj2;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `operator<` a template, and constrain the type with `std::enable_if`. E.g.

```
template <typename P>
auto operator<(const P& r) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<P, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>>, bool> {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. `*this` is available after `->`. I simplified the example in my question, originally I need it for a static member function. Could it be done for a static member function?

Comment: It seems to be working also for static member functions. `static auto memfun(const P& r) -> ...`

Comment: @S.M. Really? I got error with [`static` member function](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d8LskEZuREWFm62X); for which it seems impossible.

Comment: @S.M. Clang rejects it and I think it's correct (even I'm not sure).